# File Link is not wok in laravel on localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: php, laravel

I am using php artisan serve to serve on local host http://127.0.0.1:8000 , then files I upload surely  exist in storage folder but when I am creating links like:

```
 public function getFeaturedImageLinkAttribute()
{
    $file = $this->getFirstMedia('featured_image');
    if (! $file) {
        return null;
    }

    return '<a href="' . $file->getUrl() . '" target="_blank">' . $file->file_name . '</a>';
}
```

---

```
 public function getUrl(string $conversionName = ''): string
{
    $urlGenerator = UrlGeneratorFactory::createForMedia($this, $conversionName);

    return $urlGenerator->getUrl();
}
```

links I get is like : http://127.0.0.1/storage/6/image.jpg

which is not woking but when I do : http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/6/image.jpg 
it works so my question is how to make my links work?

.env file:

APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

already tried - php artisan storage:link

Comment: Can you show codes of getUrl() function?

Comment: just updated kindly check @tokmbo

Comment: @jsotola yes ..

Comment: hmm, so getUrl() called other function.. and did you create getFeaturedImageLinkAttribute()? If that so, I suggest you to store your image name to database and retrieve it

Comment: yes getFeaturedImageLinkAttribute() its also there  and file name came from data base only table called media. @tokmbo

Comment: Try changing APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: What is you do `asset($file->getUrl())` and comment `APP_URL` ? Or use `getFullUrl()`

Comment: what is `UrlGeneratorFactory`?

Comment: @lagbox I believe he's using [laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary)

Comment: Please share more details. What does "not working" mean? What have you tried to debug **why** something is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

try first:

```
 - php artisan storage:link
 - set the default storage disk to public or you'll have to specify the disk the images are stored while retrieving it.
 - Save the file name on the database or cache system to help you to generate the URL
```

Check the example bellow:

in My controller i have

```
public function saveImage(Request $request){

        //First apply the validation rules

        $file = $request->file('image');
        $url = Storage::disk('public')->put('folder/to/save', $file);

        $image = new MyImageModel();
        $image->path = $url;
        $image->global_url = Storage::disk('public')->url($url); //this is optional
        $image->save();


        //return the propper response
    }
```

In my model in this case **MyImageModel** i've the url method

```
    public function url(){
        return $this->global_url;
        //or
        return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->url);
    }
```

and in my view i can just say:

```
<img src="{{$image->url()}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your App url is mistake  just change it to this

APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: No no it was this APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 only, I was just testing it by changing its last digit but it won't reflect anyway

Comment: Change it and remove all cache router, config  and views and update composer then that works

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in the .env file the `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` could be set as this during development so that the pictures would be loaded without using static links. I use this during dev with MAMP so that the pictures are loaded concurrently.

Also for everytime you pull from git don't forget to `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score -1):

try this...

http://127.0.0.1/storage/app/public/6/image.jpg  // add this '/app/public/' part from controller.